# How to prepere a template, to list one element from the list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, list-template

I must prepere a template to list to show one element from the list. How should I prepere this? Can I use a InfoPath? How should I do it ? Only one element from list when I want to show this element on template ? Could I put there a functionarity to print tis element with a template on printer ?

Comment: Many questions in 1 question. Its not clear to me what you exactly want

Comment: How to prepere a template to print one element from list on PDF or printer ?I must do template which I can print on printer. It should print element whicjh I choose with template.

Comment: I saw thar It could be done by Acces, but could I find print button and prepere a template on html to print elements.